# pbcopy/pbpaste not same behaviour as copy and paste Mac OS

Tags: bash, mac, copy-paste

Running the latest version of Mac OS Mojave. I do:

```
pbcopy < dir/sw7.s
pbpaste > dir/testpaste.mips.s
```

that copies the contents of sw7.s to testpaste, and the file size is exactly the same. However, when I do

```
touch dir/testpaste.mips.s
```

and then manually copy and paste from sw7 to the new file, the file size is slightly less!!! I want it to be less, the manual copy paste gives the correct result because the higher file size seems to corrupt my program.

Comment: Are these binary files? `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` operate on text data, and aren't safe for general binary data. And if the file size is getting smaller, *something* is going wrong. Also, what do you mean by "manual copy paste"?

Comment: by manual i mean command c command v. There is regular text in the .s files, the same thing happens even if I use .txt files.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way to copy files from the shell is to use the `cp` command.

`pbcopy` and `pbpaste` are mainly about allowing you to send a shell command's stdout to the clipboard, or use the clipboard for a shell command's stdin. stdin/stdout from shell commands is *usually* about 7-bit ASCII text, and commands or the shell itself often add a newline at the end of the output. So don't use those commands for copying files. Use `cp`.

Comment: cp copies the file which is not what I want. The file has some sort of corruption, I want to simulate manual copy and pasting but in bash/automatically.

Comment: Manual copy and pasting of the files via their icons in the Finder, to do a Finder copy? That doesn't cause their data to cross the clipboard. Finder fakes that. Or do you mean opening each file in an editor, selecting the source file's entire contents within the editor, copying that, and then pasting into the other editor window that shows the contents of the destination file? That traverses the clipboard, but in that case the editor app is responsible for what it sends to the clipboard on copy and how it deals with the clipboard contents on paste. Nothing like pbcopy/pbpaste.

Comment: yeah opening it in an editor. I think it was to do with the new line characters windows inserted into the file that are different on unix

Comment: Okay, I think we ran into an "[XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)" here. It's usually better to ask your real end-goal question (maybe something like, "How can I automate copying and pasting between two editor windows in _app_?"). I encourage you to delete this Question post and try again, asking your real end-goal question this time.